# Why can't getopt be used again?

Tags: c, getopt

I need to read a string line by line to figure out the logic of an event log. I have the code below that tests reading a string line by line, delimitate each line by the space character, store each token into a `char *argv[]`, and use it in `getopt`.

```
// Format: (-A | -L) (-E | -G) <Name> -T <Timestamp> [-R <Room ID>]
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *testString = "-A -E bob -T 1 -R 1\n-L -G   John -T 2  -R  2   \n -A   -G Me -T    02   ";
    const char *curr_line = testString;

    // read line by line
    while (curr_line)
    {   
        char *token;    // token for strtok()
        char *argv[9];  // mock argv
        int argc = 1;   // argument counter
        int opt = -1;   // for getopt()

        // for line splitting
        const char *next_line = strchr(curr_line, '\n');
        int curr_line_len = next_line ? (next_line - curr_line) : strlen(curr_line);

        int test_index = 0; // for testing

        // allocate space for current line
        char *tempStr = (char *)malloc(curr_line_len + 1);

        if (tempStr)
        {

            strncpy(tempStr, curr_line, curr_line_len);
            tempStr[curr_line_len] = '\0';
            memset(argv, '\0', 9);
            printf("Line: %s\n", tempStr);

            token = strtok(tempStr, " ");
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                argv[argc] = token;
                argc++;
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
            argv[0] = "test";

            // for testing 
            while(strcmp(argv[test_index], "\0") != 0) {
                printf("Token: %s\n",argv[test_index]);
                test_index++;
            }
            printf("argc is %d\n", argc);

            while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ALE:G:T:R:")) != -1)
            {
                switch (opt)
                {
                case 'A':
                    printf("A\n");
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    printf("L\n");
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    printf("E %s\n", optarg);
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    printf("G %s\n", optarg);
                    break;

                case 'T':
                    printf("T %s\n", optarg);
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    printf("R %s\n", optarg);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("unknown option\n");
                }
            }

            free(tempStr);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("malloc error\n");
            exit(255);
        }

        curr_line = next_line ? (next_line + 1) : NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem right now is that `getopt` only operates on the first loop. It automatically terminates for all subsequent lines. The testing code I wrote prints this following output:

```
Line: -A -E bob -T 1 -R 1
Token: test
Token: -A
Token: -E
Token: bob
Token: -T
Token: 1
Token: -R
Token: 1
argc is 8
A
E bob
T 1
R 1
Line: -L -G   John -T 2  -R  2
Token: test
Token: -L
Token: -G
Token: John
Token: -T
Token: 2
Token: -R
Token: 2
argc is 8
Line:  -A   -G Me -T    02
Token: test
Token: -A
Token: -G
Token: Me
Token: -T
Token: 02
Token: 2
argc is 6
```

You can see that each line is read correctly, and the tokens are well delimitated. But `getopt` only works once. I'm leaning towards some type of memory allocation issue but I can't tell what's wrong here.

Note `argv` is initiated with `9` because the arguments cannot have more than 9 arguments.

Comment: `memset(argv, '\0', 9);` isn't going to zero the whole array, missing `*sizeof(*argv)`

Comment: I don't see `optreset` mentioned anywhere in `getopt`'s documentations, can someone elaborate?

Comment: I don't see `optreset` in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) either, but I do see: *"The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed
       in argv.  The system initializes this value to 1.  The caller can
       reset it to 1 to restart scanning of the same argv, or when scanning
       a new argument vector."*

Comment: OP asked then [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218792/reading-line-by-line-as-command-arguments) recently.

Comment: yes but it's a different issue here @Weather Vane

Comment: I was only giving the background, pleased you moved on.